# iOS8: viewDidLayoutSubviews() hides elements in Storyboard Auto-Layout

Tags: swift, ios8, autolayout

Setup:

I have a View Controller that consists of a `View` and a `Container View`.

I have setup the `View` and the `Container View` using class sizes.

The code below adds the gradient just fine:

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var graphView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!
    let backgroundColor = CAGradientLayer().graphViewBackgroundColor()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        backgroundColor.frame = self.graphView.bounds
        self.graphView.layer.addSublayer(backgroundColor)

    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

There are no constraints laid out in code.

**Problem:**

However, I do have a label with black background that is not appearing.  If I comment out the following lines, the label appears:

```
    //backgroundColor.frame = self.graphView.bounds
    //self.graphView.layer.addSublayer(backgroundColor)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Question:**

Why is the gradient hiding the UILabel element that is in Auto-layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried bringing the label to the front?

`graphView.bringSubviewToFront(label)`

Comment: is there a way to push the gradient in the back?  I have 15 other elements.  Do I have to call them all one-by-one to bring to front?

Comment: Yeah, instead of `bringSubviewToFront` you can do `sendSubviewToBack`

Comment: `self.view .sendSubviewToBack(self.graphView)` ? is not working

Comment: Assuming `containerView ` is the parent view of your graphView, `containerView. sendSubviewToBack(graphView)` should work

Comment: ContainerView is below that's holding the tableview.  graphView is on top.

Comment: Is this your how your view hierarchy is? `containerView` > `tableView` > `label` > `graphView`

Comment: No, ViewController that has two views.  One is a containerView and the other is graphView (UIView).  The label in on top of the graphView.

Comment: ah ok. I think this would be an easier solution. `self.graphView.layer.insertSublayer(backgroundColor, atIndex: 0)`

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try this in the AM.  What's the difference?